# Export my whole AWS architecture into file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, subnet, amazon-vpc, aws-cli, aws-directory-service

In AWS, I have a VPC with many components inside, including subnets, security groups, gateways, load balancers, target groups, many instances, and others.

Is there any ways to export my whole architecture and components into a file, say`XML` or something?

Comment: Not to my knowledge - you could get much of the way there by using the AWS CLI's output and combining it yourself into a format of some sort. Maybe you're tackling this from the wrong end, though: You can use a configuration management system like Ansible, Puppet, Chef, etc. or something like [AWS CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) to *define* what your infrastructure should look like, and they'll actually create it for you.

Comment: Ummm, too bad. This looks like a must-to-have feature! Initially things were created manually, so no initial template for us.

Answer (score 13):

You can use [CloudFormer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html) to export your existing AWS infrastructure into CloudFormation template. Alternatively you can use [terraforming](https://github.com/dtan4/terraforming) ruby gem to export your infrastructure as Terraform files.